# Changing name to eliminate non-research questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am noticing lately that there are many questions being rejected because they are not *research level* questions. It is obvious that most of these questions are asked by people who never posted any other questions in here, and it is typical that they dont read the FAQ. My question is how to eliminate such rejected questions.

A suggestion:
I am wondering if we can ask stackexchange to change the name of this forum to something like "Research Level Computer Science" -- or "Advanced Theoritical CS" or any other name ... Is that possible somehow ? This would help a bet in eliminating such questions.

[I do recognize that this will not solve the main issue since there are always spammers in the internet who just want their questions to be solved and dont care about their "virtual reputation"]

Comment: a name change or other small tweaks will prob not fix the persistent "beginner questions" (which imho, against conventional wisdom here, some are not really all that easy to identify, as far as both false positives/negatives). stack exchange software is designed to be largely open to beginners & this particular site pushes strongly against that. however this site certainly does have the ability (and perhaps tendency) to push away/discourage them fairly quickly. _bzzzzt._ also question traffic has been on a long downward slide. soon there will be only one perfect question left I guess :p

Answer (score 5):

If you search back through meta, this is a question we thought about quite a lot in the beginning stages of the site.  The "compromise" is that we have an FAQ that explains what questions are acceptable, and we will sometimes keep open non-research level questions if they  lead to interesting answers.  Otherwise, inappropriate questions are closed and the respective OPs are referred to the FAQ.

I think asking to change our name is too drastic at this point.

Comment: interesting, i have not seen the other question. But note that the question was asked on Oct 2012. At that time, i guess cs.stackexchange.com was still at its beginnings. So there were no alternatives. (at the end, it s just a suggestion).